# Mongoose update individual model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The mongoose docs clearly demonstrated how to update a model given a model class, like so:

```
Tank.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
```

If we do need the document returned in our application there is another, often better, option:

```
Tank.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.send(tank);
});
```

but I can't find the syntax for updating a model that I already have in hand, that would be something like:

```
tank.update({ $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
```

does this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example from your question is supported:

```
tank.update({ $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
```

The documentation for that flavor of `update` is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) as it's part of the base `Document` instead of `Model` itself.

However, keep in mind that the `tank` object you're calling it on won't be updated, just the actual document in the database.

Comment: I wonder why mongoose/mongo doesn't barf when you don't put the $set operator there. If I pass in a staight object as the first argument, it doesn't return an error and it probably should

Comment: @AlexMills That's actually defined behavior. See the Note in [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) for `update`.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply `.save()`:

```
tank.size = "large"
tank.save(callback)
```

where your callback has three arguments: `error, savedTank, count`:

[Here it is in the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).

It can be slightly more complex with arrays, but there are tons of questions addressing them.

Comment: thanks, you may also be interested in what @JohnnyHK just posted as a comment aka this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

Comment: @AlexMills yep, just keep in mind that `.update()` doesn't pass the updated document to the callback in the same manner that `findByIdAndUpdate()` does.